# Best practice Magento dev environment, how do teams develop Magento?

Tags: magento2, best-practice

I'm trying to set up a dev environment for my team to work together on 1 Magento project. But I don't know if I should use a shared server with a Magento installation or if we should all install Magento locally and share a database/git repo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a silver bullet solution on this.
All I can say is how we do it.
We've setup a docker environment using the suite created by [Fabrizio Balliano](https://github.com/fballiano/docker-magento2).
We made some additional changes to it.

- we added a sample data sql with some products that gets installed when the db container is created (using the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` feature).
- we created a `make` file that contains some wrappers for the docker commands because they are hard to remember. Example `make ssh` is an alias for `@docker exec -it --user www-data magento.container.name.here bash` in order to get cli access to the container. `make uninstall` will destroy the containers and cleanup after them. `make install` will create all containers and so on.

This way, everyone has the same environment and the same settings (that can be matched to the live server).
We needed at one point to add elasticsearch to the project. We just pulled up a docker image for elasticsearch and that's it. It got versioned and everyone had it at the next `git pull`.
When a new person comes in the project they just `git clone` the repo, run `make install` and everything is set up.
Draw backs:
 - it only works perfectly on linux. It can be made to work on mac (and maybe windows) but we did not bother.
 - it introduces dev dependencies like `docker` and `gnu makefile`.

Comment: do you have snippets of scripts. Can you share the makefile and compose

Answer (score 1):

We personally have installed Magento locally through [Bitnami VM](https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/virtual-machine) and we share a git repository. When we have to get the project into a production server we just clone the repo and the database.

Comment: we do like the bitnami VM because it's pretty performant and easy to set up, but won't we have problems with the database if we each made different changes to it? Or can we use version control on it?

Comment: Yes and no, it depends. Personally, we are 3 in our dev team, so if we need to upgrade the db locally because someone has made a change, he just shares it via Slack or shared folders and we upload it and change the local urls. It doesn't take more than 5 minutes and we don't do it that often. But of course if you have a 10/20 or even more, it might not be the best/suitable option.